# How can I put two responsive tables in one column?

Tags: html, css

How can I put a responsive table next to the another one? 
I used the HTML codes which I shared below. However, the second table has been placed under the first one.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6">
      <center><h4>GÜNLÜK DEMİR FİYATLARI</h4></center>
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Bölge</th>
               <th>Tarih</th>
               <th>Kalın Demir</th>
               <th>İnce Demir</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
      <center><h4>PİYASA FİYATLARI</h4></center>
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Döviz</th>
               <th>Tarih</th>
               <th>Alış</th>
               <th>Satış</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaVYG.png)

Here is the full and live [link](http://yedek.aycaayder.com/borsa.php).

How can I put two responsive tables in one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your tables (and headers) with the col- classes.  I created a working fiddle.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
    <center><h4>GÜNLÜK DEMİR FİYATLARI</h4></center>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Bölge</th>
    <th>Tarih</th>
    <th>Kalın Demir</th>
    <th>İnce Demir</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
    <center><h4>PİYASA FİYATLARI</h4></center>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Döviz</th>
    <th>Tarih</th>
    <th>Alış</th>
    <th>Satış</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ouwf90br/

Answer (score 0):

Add html like this:

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
            <center><h4>GÜNLÜK DEMİR FİYATLARI</h4></center>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Bölge</th>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th>Kalın Demir</th>
                    <th>İnce Demir</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <center><h4>PİYASA FİYATLARI</h4></center>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Döviz</th>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th>Alış</th>
                    <th>Satış</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
            <center><h4>GÜNLÜK DEMİR FİYATLARI</h4></center>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Bölge</th>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th>Kalın Demir</th>
                    <th>İnce Demir</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <center><h4>PİYASA FİYATLARI</h4></center>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Döviz</th>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th>Alış</th>
                    <th>Satış</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that add css for remove margin from row:

```
.table-row .row{margin:0}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @BhumiPatel

Comment: Your Welcome!  @Katzenlieb